# The mobile application cannot connect to the web service

Tags: windows, mobile, service, connect

I have a mobile app webservice client that connects to a WCF webservice(on my PC) deployed in a WiMo Device. The OS is Windows Mobile 6.0. It is connected to my PC using a USB cable and ActiveSync 4.5.

Problem:

When I use a mobile emulator to run the application, it was able to connect to the web service successfully. But if I use the mobile phone to run the application, it cannot connect to the web service. However, I can view the webservice's test webpage using phone's browser(IE) (http://153.xxx.xxx.xxx:8080/Design_Time_Addresses/SOAP11demo/Service1/)

Can you guys help me identify on what is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is pretty simple (foolish me). Change the localhost into IP address. not only in the .config file of the server but also the generated stub classes of the client :))